# How to allow a Manager to forward a users email to another user? (Self Manage)

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2007

How can I allow a Manager to forward "User A's" email to "User B".

Currently I.T personelle are doing this at the server level, but we'd like to allow the managers to "Self Manage" this.

We are using Exchange 2007 running on Windows Server 2003. Users are all running Windows XP and Outlook 2007.

Comment: E-Mail system? Security in place? Operating System? Anything?

Comment: Sorry, Exchange 2007 running on Windows Server 2003. Users are all running Windows XP and Outlook 2007.

Comment: what was your answer to this? I need to know as well, I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using the "out of office settings"

you can use these to forward emails automatically to other users if you are not there. I'm kind of assuming that's what you mean. If I'm wrong please disregard.

Comment: Yes, but when the users are absent the are not aware of their future absent, this is why we require Managers of that dept. to make the change for the user.

thanks for your reply.

Comment: I.E - John calls in sick first thing in the morning. So John needs his email forwarded to another user. John is not in to set the rule to forward his email. Therefore, Manager Robert, would forward John's email to Cindy.